# ¿Cómo recorrer por columnas un archivo CSV?

Tags: c#, string, csv, lista

Lo que quiero hacer es que en un `List<string>` pueda guardar cada uno de los campos de la primera columna de un archivo CSV

El archivo CSV esta conformado así:

> Folder1,Titulo1,Ubicacion1,02/06/2017 10:00,02/06/2017
>   11:00,Descripcion1 Folder2,Titulo2,Ubicacion2,03/06/2017
>   10:00,03/06/2017 11:00,Descripcion2
>   Folder1,Titulo3,Ubicacion3,04/06/2017 10:00,04/06/2017
>   11:00,Descripcion3

Lo que quiero es que en la variable de tipo `List<string>` se guarden los datos de la primera columna, es decir "Folder1, Folder2, Folder1"

Lo que tengo realizado es solo el recorrido por renglón.

Este es el código:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(csvPath);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Line -> " + line);
    counter++;
}
file.Close();
MessageBox.Show("There were " + counter + " lines.");
```

En donde `csvPath` es la ruta del archivo CSV que la obtengo desde un `openFileDialog`

¿Cómo recorrer por columnas un archivo CSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) para dividir la línea en columnas y luego acceder al primer elemento del array resultante:

```
var lista = new List<string>();
using (var file = new StreamReader(csvPath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lista.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
    }
}
```

Pero cuidado, que esto asume que los datos se parecen a lo que pusistes en la pregunta, donde los datos no tienen caracteres especiales o comas, lo que causaría que los datos CSV incluyan comillas dobles que hay que parsear correctamente. Si tus datos son más complicados de lo que pusistes en tu ejemplo, será mejor usar una librería diseñada para parsear datos CSV correctamente (ejemplo: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)).

Ejemplo usando `CsvHelper`:

```
var lista = new List<string>();
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(csvPath)))
{
    while(csv.Read())
    {
        lista.Add(csv.GetField(0));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

E inspirándome de la respuesta de @Flxtr con la excelente idea de usar LINQ para simplificar el código, yo lo haría de esta forma:

```
var lista = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath).Select(line => line.Split(',')[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: ¡Qúe gran idea! Bastante simplificado a una sola línea :D

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de resolverlo es usando Linq:

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();

lista = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(csvPath)
        let parts = p.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        select new
        {
            columna = parts[0].ToString()
        }).Select(t => t.columna.ToString()).ToList();
```